# Neo4j - Wrapping/Inheriting a Node object

Tags: lucene, indexing, neo4j

I'm developing kind of a social network with neo4j, and i wanted to make my `Node` object a bit more specific for my own needs. Does it considered a good practice to wrap a neo4j `Node` object or to inherit from it?
My problem with the wrapping approach arises when indexing the nodes objects with the built in Lucene engine. For example, what benefits will i earn if i'll wrap my `Node` object with a "Profile" class (with methods such as "addFriend", "setFirstName", etc..), but on the other hand, whenever i will run a query against my index i'll get back raw `Node` objects and not my wrapped objects? I can make some dirty solution for this case, by saving a reference for the wrapped object inside my node properties, but it looks very strange for me to do it.
What would you recommend to do in such case, in order to get a clean and well designed code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that wrapping a Node does not lead to very maintainable code/design. As you mentioned, one thing you need to take care of is not returning a Node but translating it to your domain object.

If your object has mostly getX methods, then you can just execute Cypher queries, compose your domain object(s) and return those. You don't even need to wrap the Node in this case- all you need is some property that you can use to look up the Node.

If you have setX methods, then you can update the Node via Cypher statements either via a save that updates all properties or on each setX (not great, as you'd be updating too often the setX method now implies persistence). Either of the two approaches does not require the Node to be wrapped.

I tried in earlier projects to wrap the Node but found that it leads to much more trouble and a generally smelly design. Now I work with pure domain POJOS's and keep Neo4j code in the persistence layer only, and this works much better for me. You haven't mentioned which language you're using- if Java, then I believe [Spring Data](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/spring) can take care of a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

Put your search code INTO the class they belongs to.

If you need to get, I don't know, something like getFriends from a Post class, you will create the method fromPosts into the Person class, and the getFriends method into Post.

From post, you will call the query from Person class, execute the query and return an Array / List of the nodes mapped into the Person class.

So your getFriends method into the Post class will be something like:

> Person.fromPosts(self).results.map { |node| Person.new(node) }

Is simple to do that doing just a map of the result with a Person.new (or new Person, depend from which language are you using) and pass the node to the Person. This means that you must have a new method that populate object from a node.

Comment: I don't see how it solves my design problem... my query results will still be of the the type Node, which gives me no information extra information. what if i have different type of nodes? I would like to able to index my wrapper class, and not the underlying Node type.

Comment: you mean that you want to do a query that return different object from different classes?

Comment: yes. I saw that the Index class is generic, which mostly used as Index<Node>. Is it considered good practice to wrap/inherit the node class, and use it as generic parameter for the Index class?

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Data Neo4j](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j) is the definitive solution to your need, it maps annotated entity classes to Neo4j with advanced mapping functionality and provides access to nodes and relationships at different levels of abstraction.